What is the practical difference between function and lambda in C++?
If I am correct, the key difference between regular function and lambda is that regular function definition is a statement and lambda function definition is an expression. This comes with practical results like the ability to write lambda definition inplace in code and this is the main usage of lambdas (along with passing lambdas as parameters and returning as results), as I understand.
Meanwhile I see in many places of code constructs like below where lambda defined as a constexpr which creates constexpr entity which holds anonymous function. What is the practical reason of such a syntax (I mean, why people use it widely) and what could be the example where such definition make difference from the definition of the function below it?
constexpr auto lambda = []() {
};

void function()
{
}

int main()
{
    lambda();
    function();
}


Lamdas are much more expressive and allow for (more easy) functional composition e.g. you can have functions generating lambdas (e.g. wrap infrastructure around another call/lambda).  auto lambda is NOT an anonymous lambda, it is a lambda with a compiler defined type (that you cannot know). For practical use have a look at things like std::sort .

In your particular case, the lambda is mostly just syntactic sugar.   The main functional difference is that the type of lambda is unknowable and unique (formally unspecified), whereas function has the same type as any other function that accepts no arguments and returns void.

@PepijnKramer, I mostly focused on this particular case and I would agree with Peter that out of context in this particular case this is syntactic sugar caused just by authors' habit to use lambdas instead of functions. Of course, I agree that in wider context lambdas much more flexible and in std::sort they allow to keep types in opposite to C sort style. My question is about this usage. And... I never told that this is anonymous lambda, I said that it holds anonymous function. Anyway, thank you, I got your points. Example, although, would help.

@Peter, so the question is, is this is good approach to follow this "syntactic sugar" caused (most likely) by habit of use lambdas (or possible ground for further development/refactoring and other use) or when definition and use is very straightforward it is always better to use the simplest syntax possible? Or this is a kind of gray area where one verges another?

There is generally no absolute "best". In C++ most things are rather "it depends". Is it good to be "simple" when possible, or to use the same syntax everywhere? One syntax for global functions, and another one for local ones? And don't ask about using trailing return types.  :-)

@DamirTenishev It is not just syntactic sugar. I've seen that the compiler can optmize lamdbas better sometimes.  E.g. Why can lambdas be better optimized by the compiler than plain functions?

@DamirTenishev   I tend to advocate doing things in the simplest way possible.   Not because it is necessary "best" (which is a concept that can be defined in many disparate ways).   But because mere mortals can comprehend it more easily.   When doing C++ development, ease of comprehension by a mere mortal tends to make something easier to get right.   In your specific case, I'd lean toward a function.   In other specific cases, I'd lean toward a lambda - it's hard to say without specific development goals in mind (which you haven't described).

A lambda can have internal state.  A function does not have state.  (Albeit a function may depend on global state, or local static state.)

Read about CPO and neibloid. Simplest implementation is lambda. Lambda can't be overloaded, nor will it use ADL. If the lambda invocation operator is generic, it can be directly used in functional compositions, whilst an ordinary template function need full template argument list in such contexts.

From a user point of view, anyone that has used javascript or C# or java will want to use constexpr lambdas as it is similar to anonymous functions that people are used to, as the return type is deduced.

from a technical point of view constexpr lambdas can be used where normal functions cannot be used, when a functor is expected, for example in hasher of std::unordered_map, or functions that expect a functor.
template <typename F>
void call_f(F&& f) // can only accept functors, not function pointers

a lambda will decay to a function pointer if it has no captures so a lambda can be used in any place where a normal function is expected. the call operator is also implicitly constexpr, so it is less boilerplate.
Another major advantage is that a single functor can have an overloaded call operator if it has auto parameter and you can "copy it" or take its address, while a function that uses auto is treated as an overload set and you cannot get a pointer to it. this is important for things like std::visit visitors.

one notable difference is the standard library niebloids which disables ADL, but this is most likely not the reason why the people use constexpr lambdas outside of the standard library.

As for an example wrt composability of lambdas here is one :
#include <iostream>

// example of a function that takes a lambda 
// and computes a new lambda. (for brevity I didn't
// add trait checks on fn_t, like is_invocable).

template<typename fn_t>
auto decorate(fn_t fn)
{
    auto decorated_fn = [=] {
        std::cout << "Some infrastructure before call\n";
        try
        {
            fn();
        }
        catch(const std::exception& e)
        {
            std::cout << "call failed : " << e.what() << "\n";
            return;
        }
        std::cout << "Some infrastructure after successful call\n";
    };
    return decorated_fn;
}

int main()
{
    auto decorated_fn = decorate([] { std::cout << "actual call\n"; });
    decorated_fn();
}


Thank you for the clue. Funny thing is that just days ago I implemented the prologue/epilogue in a similar way. My point is not lambdas overall, but this syntax like constexpr auto lambda =. Does your answer cover this case and I missed the point or you mean lambdas in wider sense? (I believe the string "enter code here" in the code above could be removed?)

Seems you already have the pragmatic exprience then :) The constexpr is relevant when immediately invoked at compile time.  It would allow the lambda to be evaluated at compile time (and not make it into the final binary)

A lot here depends on what you mean by "practical".
They don't arise much in most typical use, but there are some differences due to the fundamental difference between a lambbda expression and a function. In particular, a lambda expression is really a shorthand way of creating a class and an object of that class. The class always overloads operator() and (if the lambda doesn't capture anything) also a conversion to "pointer to function".
The equivalent of a lambda expression like auto lambda = [](){}; is really something like this:
struct HiddenName {
    void operator()() const {}
} lambda;

When the lambda captures something like this:
auto lambda = [i](int j) { return i + j; };

That's specifying that the class will also have a ctor and a data member:
class HIDDEN {
    int const i;
public:
    HIDDEN(int i) : i(i) {}
    int operator()(int j) const {  return i + j; }
} lambda;

But now consider a lambda that captures something by value, and modifies the value it captures.
auto lambda = [i](int j) mutable { return ++i + j; };

This makes a copy of i from the surrounding environment, then modifies its own copy. But it's a member of an object, so we can do (most of) the same sorts of things with it that we can with other objects. For example, we can copy it to get two different things that can be called, each with its own internal state:
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int foo[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    int i=0;
    auto lambda = [i](int j) mutable { return ++i + j; };

    // call `lambda` to increment its `i` a few times:
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        std::cout << lambda(foo[i]) << "\n"; 
    }

    auto lambda2 = lambda; // lambda is an object. We can copy it.
    // lambda2 is a copy of lambda,so lamda::i == lambda2::i

    // increment lambda's i, but not lambda2's i
    std::cout <<lambda(10) << "\n"; 

    // lambda::i != lambda2::i:
    std::cout << "lambda(0) = " << lambda(0) << '\n';
    std::cout << "lambda2(0) = " << lambda2(0) << '\n';
}

Live on Godbolt
I don't know whether that qualifies as "practical" or not though. On one hand, you can write code that demonstrates a clear difference between the two--there's no way to do the same thing with a function. On the other hand, I've been using C++ since before it had lambda expressions at all, and I've never done anything like that in real code (in fact, I'm not at all sure I've ever used a mutable lambda in real code).

I played a bit with functions and lambda declarations in C++, and here's what i found:
Constexpr lambdas and constexpr functions are not the same thing. In fact, constxpr functions does just what you think it does. It's a compile-time function that will return the value at compile time, and the compiler will utilize it to a value.
Constexpr lambdas, on the other hand, are being utilized to a set of instructions that are not stored in a variable (In simple terms, it's a define-like assignment to a variable that may not exist in the context of the program).
If you have code like this:
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>         
int main(){
    std::vector<int> vec = {15, 19, 82, 1984, 52, 42 };
    constexpr auto lambda = [](const int a, const int b) -> bool {
        return a<b;
    };
    for (const auto n : vec){
        std::cout << n << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), lambda);
    // Eyes on this line ^

    for (const auto n : vec){
        std::cout << n << ' ';
    }

}


It'll become something like this:
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const int a, const int b) -> bool {
    return a<b;
});


Another example:
const double PI = 3.141519;
constexpr float func(double num){
    return num*PI;
};
constexpr auto lambda1 = [](double num) -> double{    
    return num*PI;
};  

Compilation with flags clang++ -o main.exe main.cpp --target=x86_64-w64-mingw --std=c++17 fails with:

main.cpp:5:17: error: constexpr function never produces a constant expression [-Winvalid-constexpr]
    5 | constexpr float func(double num){
      |                 ^~~~
main.cpp:6:16: note: read of non-constexpr variable 'PI' is not allowed in a constant expression
    6 |     return num*PI;
      |    


You can also define functions like this:
auto func(double b) -> double { // -> double is optional. The return type will be defined during compilation
    // return anything related to int
}

